# process communication with signls

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, posix

I am trying to write a C program which has some number of processes. One of them sends a random signal in the range SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX to all other processes but I want this signal will be ignored in main process.I used the global variable to have randomized signal to ignore with SIG_IGN. It looks It is not helping because the main stops with real-time signal when wants to ignore the first randomized signal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t disarming_signal = 0;

void disarming_handler (int sig) {
     disarming_signal = sig;
     fprintf(stderr,"signal %d is handeled", disarming_signal);
}
int rand_range(int min_n, int max_n){
     int rand_n = rand() % (max_n - min_n) + min_n;
     return rand_n;
}
int sethandler (void (*f)(int), int sigNo) {
    struct sigaction act;
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
act.sa_handler = f;
    if (-1==sigaction(sigNo, &act, NULL))
        return -1;
return 0;
}
void sigchld_handler(int sig){ 
pid_t pid;
for(;;){
    pid=waitpid(0, NULL, WNOHANG);
    if(pid==0) return;
    if(pid<=0) {
        if(errno==ECHILD) return;
        perror("waitpid:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
}

void usage(){
fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: sappartherroryst n\n");
fprintf(stderr,"n - number of Therrorysts\n");
}

void therroryst_work(){
int s,k,t;
srand(getpid());
s = rand_range(SIGRTMIN, SIGRTMAX);
t = rand_range(10, 20);
k = t;  
if(sethandler(disarming_handler, s)){
    perror("Seting therroryst handeler");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fprintf(stderr, "[%d] I am therroryst. My disarming signal is [%d]. I will wait [%d] Sec.\n", getpid(), s, t);
while(k>0) {
    k=sleep(k);
    if(disarming_signal == s){
        fprintf(stderr, "I got signal [%d]\n.",disarming_signal);
         return ;
    }
}
fprintf(stderr, "[%d] KABOOM\n",getpid());
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
void create_therrorysts(int n){
while(n-->0){
    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            therroryst_work();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        case -1:
            perror("Fork():");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
} 
void sapper_work(){
int sig_dis, i; 
struct timespec t, tn = {1,0};
fprintf(stderr,"[%d] I am sapper.\n", getpid());
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(t=tn;nanosleep(&t,&t););
    sig_dis = rand_range(SIGRTMIN, SIGRTMAX);   
    if(kill(0, sig_dis)<0){
        perror("Disarming_send\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

fprintf(stderr,"I sended signal [%d].\n",sig_dis);  
disarming_signal = sig_dis;
}
fprintf(stderr, "end of sending");
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void create_sapper(){
switch(fork()) {
    case 0:
        sapper_work();
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    case -1:
        perror("Fork():");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
int n;
pid_t pid;

if(argc != 2){
    usage();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
n = atoi(argv[1]);  

if(n <= 0){ 
    usage();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if(sethandler(sigchld_handler, SIGCHLD)) {
    perror("Seting parent SIGCHLD:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
create_therrorysts(n);
create_sapper();
sleep(5);
for(;;) {
    if(sethandler(SIG_IGN, disarming_signal)){
        perror("Seting parent disarming111");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

for(;;){
    pid=wait(NULL);
    if(pid<0)
        switch (errno){
            case ECHILD:
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            case EINTR: 
                continue;
            default:
                perror("wait:");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Don't use printf() in a signal handler. It is not signal safe.

Comment: Yes you are right but even without it there is the problem I mentioned .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have  sleep(5) after the create_sapper and before sethandler(IGN). That means it's very likely that the signal is sent before your main process has ignored it.

EDIT: Adding comment from Jonathan Leffler into this answer as it is equally (or even more) important:

There's also a problem with setting the signal handler even if you put the sleep() after that loop - the parent doesn't get to see what the child chooses as disarming_signal.

Comment: There's also a problem with setting the signal handler even if you put the sleep() after that loop - the parent doesn't get to see what the child chooses as `disarming_signal`.

Comment: Yes, good catch. That's arguably even a bigger problem than the sleep.

Comment: I thought, It would be most likely the disarm_signal set to the random signal after sleep because without it I was getting handling out of rang signal (initial value of disarm_signal)

Comment: @Sajjad Don't understand what you mean by that last comment. Let us know if fixing both the disarm_signal and sleep problems solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry for pre. comment :)
@AlanAu I am trying to say without sleep(5) in the parent there is no chance to Ignore the random signal which is generated by sapper() because in first step  main ignore the signal with value 0 (the initial value of disarm_signal) so with out sleep(5) I got following error. ( pintf in handler is already removed )

==> Seting parent disarming111: Invalid argument

Comment: That's the second problem in your program that Jonathan pointed out. By putting the sleep in you are not fixing that problem. So you need to fix both problems. That is, 1. You need to remove the sleep. 2. You need a different way of setting the "disarming_signal" value. You can't set it in the child process and expect the parent to see that value - it won't.

Comment: Guys, actually you were right sorry I was busy but I check the points you mentioned. the only possibility for me was to block all the signals form SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX in the main no other way to find out which signals were issued by sapper and obviously it work. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got it working. On the point about setting disarming_signal. There are other ways to do it other than blocking all signals. You just need synchornisation between the parent and the child process and an IPC (pipe, shared memory, shared file, etc) for the child to tell the parent the chosen signal. That's just FYI in case you want to try that.